How to Implement Partial Update in GraphQL with Spring Boot?
I'm working on a GraphQL API using Spring Boot and I want to allow partial updates to a Client entity. Specifically, I want the user to be able to update only certain fields of the entity, like the lastUpdate field, without having to provide all the fields in the mutation. This includes handling a foreign key relationship with a Group entity.
# Define the Client type
type Client {
    endpoint: ID!
    registrationDate: String  
    lastUpdate: String        
    version: String
    group: Group
}

# Define the mutation for updating client data
extend type Mutation {
    updateClient(
        endpoint: ID!,
        registrationDate: String,
        lastUpdate: String,
        version: String,
        groupId: ID
    ): Client
}

And here's my Spring Boot controller:
@Controller
public class ClientGraphQLController {

    @Autowired
    private ClientService clientService;

    @MutationMapping
    public Client updateClient(
            @Argument String endpoint,
            @Argument String registrationDate,
            @Argument String lastUpdate,
            @Argument String version,
            @Argument Long groupId
    ) {
        Client clientDetails = new Client();
        clientDetails.setRegistrationDate(Timestamp.valueOf(registrationDate));
        clientDetails.setLastUpdate(Timestamp.valueOf(lastUpdate));
        clientDetails.setVersion(version);

        var groupOpt = groupService.getGroupById(groupId);
        groupOpt.ifPresent(clientDetails::setGroup);

        return clientService.updateClient(endpoint, clientDetails).orElse(null);
    }
}

What I want to achieve is that the updateClient mutation can perform a partial update. For example, the user should be able to update only the lastUpdate field without needing to provide the other fields, like this:
mutation {
  updateClient(
    endpoint: "client-endpoint-id",
    lastUpdate: "2024-09-23T10:00:00Z"
  ) {
    endpoint
    lastUpdate
  }
}

How can I modify my mutation and controller to support partial updates, especially when dealing with a foreign key (groupId) to another entity?

Here before updating value you can validate it like this :
if (!version.isBlank()) {       clientDetails.setVersion(version);     }
You have to do this for every updated field.

Thanks for your comment! Is there something that is more familiar to Jason patch?

You have to use third party library like <dependency>     <groupId>com.github.java-json-tools</groupId>     <artifactId>json-patch</artifactId>     <version>{version}</version> </dependency>
